# Create Kubernetes object from a file located in Github

Tags: github, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-deployment

I want to create a deployment with GitHub URL using
`kubectl create -f github.com/deployment.yaml`
That `deployment.yaml` file is located in  my private GitHub repository.
How can I authenticate my kubectl to use my GitHub private repo and create that deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply:

- [curl the file from the private repo](https://gist.github.com/Integralist/9482061)
- [pass its content to kubectl create -f](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505831/7490)

That is, from [this example](https://gist.github.com/madrobby/9476733#gistcomment-2817366):

```
USER="me"
PASSWD="mypasswd"
OUTPUT_FILEPATH="./foo"
OWNER="mycompany"
REPOSITORY="boo"
RESOURCE_PATH="project-x/a/b/c.py"
TAG="my_unit_test"
curl \
    -u "$USER:$PASSWD" \
    -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v4.raw' \
    -o "$OUTPUT_FILEPATH" \
    -L "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPOSITORY/contents/$RESOURCE_PATH?ref=$TAG"
| kubectl create -f /dev/stdin
```

Comment: getting: "error: no objects passed to create" @VonC

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN First does the curl alone works and prints the file content?

Comment: no its not..
I replaced INSERTTOKENHERE with my token.Replaced `https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/contents/path` with my gitfile url
should i do anything else?

Comment: You need to replace owner/repo with your GitHub name and repository name, but beside that, no: as long as this curl does not work, kubectl won't either.

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN See a more recent example in https://gist.github.com/madrobby/9476733#gistcomment-2817366

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN I have updated the answer, using the v4 API instead of the v3.

Comment: its working now thankyou..
Is there any other simpler(shorter) options available?

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN Not that I know of: kubectl has no notion of "remote repository", just a file.